# Gradle not syncing in Android studio (v1.1.0)

Tags: android

When I attempt to sync, I get the following error:

> The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. >Tried location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe

Maybe i need to use jdk 1.7, but I cant seem to change it, please help (I have jdk 1.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check *File*, *Project Structure*, here you can change the JDK:

[image]

Here you can select the source and target compatibility as well:

[image]

This information refers to Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

For fixing the problem inside **IntelliJ Idea** do the following :

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JVM -> Change to your appropriate JVM

Answer (score 0):

In Intellij (or Android Studio) you have to download Gradle file from the Gradle website and then go to Intellij settings choose the manual configuration, then point the Gradle address you have downloaded.

In the same issue I resolved this error like this.